# Member struct property as Primary key in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, primary-key

Let's say I have the following code:

```
public class TenantId
{
   public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

   public TenantId(Guid id)
   {
      Id = id;
   }
}

public class Tenant
{
   public TenantId Id { get; protected set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public Tenant(TenantId id, string name)
   {
      Id = id;
      Name = name;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to map TenantId as a Guid primary key in Entity Framework Code First?

I have tried the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>()
   .HasKey(m => m.Id );
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>()
   .HasKey(m => m.Id.Id );
```

Both compile, but both throw runtime exceptions. The former says it's an invalid type (must be a scalar, string or byte[]). The latter complains about an invalid expression, for not being a property.

I also tried adding an implicit conversion from TenantId to Guid, with no luck,

Comment: Why not merge both classes into a single `Tenant` class?

Comment: Mainly because I have other logic associated with my identities (i.e. custom ToString formatting, among other things) that is not shown here. It's not a real deal breaker, so if EF cannot do what I am trying to do I will probably just do that rather than switch ORMs, but it would be better if I could figure out how to do it this way :)

Comment: Any success using [complex types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.11)?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework support only scalar types, string and byte[] as the primary key. The best option for you to move property Guid Id in Tenant class. If you need to do some logic or with a key then you you can place this logic in EntityBase class, which is the parent Tenant:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    //logic with Id
}

public class Tenant : EntityBase
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a kind of solution here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T141713

- Adding a redundant string Id in the Tenant class.
- Modifying the get and set methods of the Id property.

It worked but the domain entities would get some redundant lines of code. Does anyone try to modify the mapping process of a 'dbcontext' or change the source code of EF?